# Sum of all numbers in a sequence for loop

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm doing exercises regarding loops. I'm wondering how can I get sum of all the numbers in a for loop sequence?

```
for num in (12, 1, 3, 33, -2, -5, 7, 0, 22, 4): # this is the sequence and it shouldn't be altered
    if num == 0: # once it encounters 0 it should stop
        print("Done")
        break
        continue
    else:
            print(sum(num)) # otherwise print the sum of all numbers
```

I've sorted it this way, but it's a different exercise.

```
def process(numbers):
    for num in numbers:
        if num == 0:
            break
    else:
        x = sum(numbers)
        print(x)
    return 'Done'

process(( 12, 4, 3, 33, -2, -5, 7, 0, 22, 4 ))
```

I would like to see a solution for the first case without defining a function with it's parameter of sequence, just as it is in the first code block. Thank you in advance.
print(sum(num)) doesn't work since object is not iterable.

Comment: Think of it this way... you need to set a `total` variable to 0, then just amend slightly what you're doing so you loop over each number, and if it's 0, then break, otherwise, add num to your total... then either when you've looped through all your numbers or you've hit a 0, `total` will then be your desired sum.

Comment: What do you intend `break` and `continue` to do in succession?

Comment: @DeepSpace Once it encounters 0 it stops. if there is no 0 in the sequence, than sum of all numbers should be printed.

Answer (score 4):

If we know for sure that 0 exists this can be done in a fairly cheeky way (at the cost of having to iterate the list twice and the creation of a new list):

```
sum(numbers[:numbers.index(0)])
```

But the proper way to do it is with an explicit loop like you tried, just with the correct logic:

```
def process(numbers):
    s = 0
    for num in numbers:
        if num == 0:
            break
        s += num
    print(s)
    return 'Done'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I'm more curious about the first code part, without the parameter and function. Summing the sequence of numbers in the for-loop

Comment: @EkoNezbit `.index(0)` returns the first index of 0 in the list, then the list is sliced using the slicing syntax to create a new list with all the numbers until that 0, then `sum` sums it. It will not work if there are no 0 in the list because `.index` raises a `ValueError` if it can't find the element it was given.

Comment: Is there any better solution than this? Thank you!

Comment: Yes it has a parameter named (numbers), I didn't have issues with that approach first place, since it's a tuple and sum built in function can be used. My concern is the first example where you're not creating a function but rather relying on the for loop sequence of numbers. Do I have to create a tuple or a list to store it and from there to use sum?

Comment: The 'cheeky' (but properly Pythonic) way will always work if you always append a `[0]` at the list ...

Comment: @usr2564301 nice workaround. unfortunately we don't have a non-inplace `append`/`insert` in order to still be done in a single line